# Help!!! Http 500 error

Tags: fatal-error

My magento site suddenly stopped opening and is throwing an http 500 error. After activating diplay errors in my index.php file the site shows:

Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 35

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: check this once : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941909/magento-fatal-error-website-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Change settings in your httpd.conf file from  **Allow Override none** to **Allow Override all**